# Converting numbers to MM:SS format in Cross-tab

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, crosstab

I'm trying to convert a value in Cross-tab of Crystal report into a MM:SS format. I used the following steps: Right-click summary > Format Field > Display String > x+2

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar curr := CurrentFieldValue;
NumberVar mins := Truncate(curr / 60);
NumberVar secs := Remainder(curr, 60);
ToText(mins, 0, "") & ":" & ToText(secs, 0, "")
```

The results are ok when the secs is not 0. Example: `4:30'

But, I am having problems when `secs` is 0, the result is (for 4 minutes): `4:0`

I would like to have the output as `4:00`, with the seconds display as always a 2 digit number.

Thank you for all your help

Comment: For one, you don't need `WhilePrintingRecords`.

Answer (score 0):

You my [ElapsedTime](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/10/18/crystal-reportscustom-functionselapsedtime/) function in conditional-formatting expression.

Answer (score 0):

I used this instead, and it worked :)

```
NumberVar curr := CurrentFieldValue;
NumberVar mins := Truncate(curr / 60);
NumberVar secs := Remainder(curr, 60);
ToText(mins, 0, "") & ":" & ToText(secs, '00')
```